# Export Release Build failed in Flash Builder 4.6 with too many SWC Library Projects into one main Project

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I had one Adobe AIR project with modular architecture which was containing around 2200 files and it was taking too much time to build.

Now we are planning to run it on multiple platforms like (web, desktop etc.), so we had separated it out in small library projects...

These library projects are inter-dependent and child library projects are added to top level library project's build path...

And also some libraries are added to main project's path...

Currently we had separated it in small 31 projects, in which there is one main Adobe AIR project which contains around 50 files and two other library projects with major files around 500 and 1050 files...

Now we got some improvements in build time...

**But when we are exporting release build for main project, flash builder is compiling all dependent projects, so flash builder failed to build the project and we got OutOfMemory Error...**

Sometimes it gives ***"internal build error with log of java.NullPointer"*** and sometimes ***"one or more errors in build process with no error log"***..
I had tried all options for heap error, internal build error etc.

But still I am not able to export release build...

So any ideas how can I make a release or any alternate solutions ??

Comment: If FlashBuilder can't take it, you'll have to use a build tool of some kind (ANT, FlexMojos, GradleFx, ...). You could also try to allocate more memory to FlashBuilder in its 'ini' file.

Comment: I had already given maximum memory in FlashBuilder.ini
But still it fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got the solution to export Release build...
We had tried one alternate way, in which not that much memory is consumed...

First of all we had cleaned all the library projects, and step by step, we had build those all projects..
After that we had build main project...

Then we had removed all the library projects from build path and we had created one separate folder in which we had put all the library SWC files from bin-debug of particular library projects...

Then that folder is included in build path of main project...

And we had created a build...

Thanks to everyone for help...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is due to Java heap memory. This issue happen to be common for Flash Builder 4.5 and above. I am not sure which builder version you are using but hope following links can help.

http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2010/02/improving_compiler_performance.html

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/sluggish-performance-out-memory-errors.html

http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/09/improving-flash-builders-performance.html

Comment: I had already tried out these all solutions...
But still we are not able to export Release...